# How do I change the format dropdown box of the TinyMCE ruby plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'd like to only allow h2 and h3, but I'm not sure how to edit the list in the dropdown shown by adding the 'formatselect' button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your tiny mce init file

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    theme_advanced_blockformats : "h2,h3"
});
```

[docs](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration)

Comment: Although, being a rails plugin, I fixed it in the controller in: uses_tiny_mce( ... :theme_advanced_blockformats => "h2,h3,p" ... )